# SQL - How to Return Max Results of Count without the count appearing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on my homework and having a VERY difficult time trying to figure out to ONLY have the Artist Name appear who has the highest number of tracks.

While I get the answer correctly, it continues to show the artist name and the number of tracks.   Just need the artist name.  Tried to use WHERE, HAVING.  Nothing seems to work.    Any ideas?

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Artist.Name 'ArtistName',
    COUNT(*)  TrackName
FROM Artist
JOIN Album ON
    Artist.ArtistId = Album.AlbumId
JOIN Track ON
    Album.AlbumId = Track.AlbumId
GROUP BY Artist.Name
ORDER BY TrackName DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `count(*)` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.Name as ArtistName
FROM Artist a JOIN
     Album al
     ON a.ArtistId = al.AlbumId join
     Track t
     ON al.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
GROUP BY a.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- The use of `as` for column aliases.
- The removal of the single quotes around the column alias.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The introduction of table aliases.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Good answer. Many people (including me when beginning SQL) _intuitively_ assume that when using `group by` an aggregation function must appear in the `select`. However, using an aggeration in `order by` is totally legal and useful.

Comment: Gordon - Thank you so much - you are my hero for today!

Comment: PhllipD - I obviously was under that assumption as well.   Looks like I need to get a little more bold and start using the aggregate functions in other areas than under the SELECT function